# Как ограничить доступ к API сайта?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Вот у меня есть телеграмм бот на aiogram и сайт на django, я хочу создать API для сайта на django rest framework, чтобы бот мог обращаться к api и либо получать записи, либо добавлять, либо изменять записи в бд. Здесь у меня встает вопрос безопасности доступа - как сделать так, чтобы к api мог обращаться только мой бот и никто из вне? Пока в голову приходит только создать какой нибудь токен и всегда при запросе к api передавать его (токен) и сверять его с тем, который будет храниться на сервере с django, но есть подозрения, что это не очень безопасно.

Comment: Никому не показывайте этот токен — и будет безопасно

Comment: А проверка id бота чем не вариант?

Comment: @Николай id бота публично известен, как его можно использовать для проверки?

Comment: Request + id вполде достаточные параметры

Comment: @Николай что такое Request?

Answer (score 0):

[У DRF уже реализован тип аутентификации по токену](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)